# How to check if my VPS Apache hosting does GZIP on response?

Tags: apache-2.2, http, gzip

I have DreamHost VPS hosting, the server is Apache. When I load my web-site in the browser, and inspect the HTTP reqests/responses in my browser's dev tools, I can see that my browser sends

```
Accept-Encoding    gzip, deflate
```

in all HTTP requests it makes (for all file types). However, when I inspect the HTTP responses, I see this header for the main HTML file:

```
Content-Encoding    gzip
```

but this header is **not** present in HTTP responses for my JS, CSS, and image files. Does this mean that my server doesn't GZIP these types of files?

Comment: You can check performance issues using online tools like http://WebPageTest.org (click the Performance Review tab after running the test). If you need help configuring mod_gzip for Apache, you're best bet is to post your current configuration. We have several people who know mod_gzip inside and out.

Comment: @ChrisS I've done that test. It indicates that my js, and css files are **not** being gzipped. I'll have to sort this out with my hosting provider. I have managed hosting, so I'm not sure how much I am able to configure myself; I didn't notice any "GZIP" options in my "panel".

Comment: Ah, so you don't have a VPS then... You just have managed hosting. That does make a difference.

Comment: @ChrisS As far as I know, I have [VPS hosting](http://dreamhost.com/servers/vps/). I wrote "managed", because I didn't have to configure anything, i.e. it came pre-configured. DreamHost writes that it provides "High Level of Control", so I guess it's not managed then.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it means that its not gzip these files.

Test your setting using Yslow, https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/yslow/ . It will give you more guidelines to optimize your server.

Comment: YSlow doesn't seem to work in my Firefox `-.-`. I have the latest versions of both Firefox, and YSlow plug-in.

Comment: Yslow is available for chrome as well.